# Apache websocket setup

Tags: apache, websocket, config, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up websocket on my local machine to test it but I simply can't get it to work, nor find any guide that actually solves it.

So to sum up, can anyone tell me what's wrong with my settings?

I'm running Ububtu 16.04 and Apache 2.4.18
I have mod_proxy and mod_proxy_wstunnel enabeled

my Apache config looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName socket.localhost

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass "/ws2/"  "ws://localhost:8546/"
    ProxyPass "/wss2/"  "wss://localhost:8546/"
</VirtualHost>
```

On the client side I have this javaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = new WebSocket('ws://socket.localhost');
    socket.send('Test');
</script>
```

And I'm running

```
netcat -p 8546 -l
```

To see any connection

And lastly I have this line in my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   socket.localhost
```

Whenever I run the JavaScript I get the error

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://socket.localhost/.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You javascript code should utilize the address `ws://socket.localhost/ws2`, since this is what you have configured in the Apache proxy configuration.

Do you actually have a websocket server running at `ws://localhost:8546`? You don't mention that in your description.

Comment: As stated in the question I have netcat running on port 8546, while not a websocket server it will output anything sent to it, which is all I need to test if the ProxyPass works.

You were right on why it doesn't work though.