# How do I setup websockets on apache using this tutorial, with just built in apache modules?

Tags: apache, websocket, uniform-server

I'm trying to [use these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42129773/337306) to setup a websockets connection on my localhost apache webserver and it's not working.

I have the `mod_proxy_wstunnel` and `mod_proxy modules` turned on so I should have the capability of running websockets on localhost. Nowadays Apache webserver has websockets support built in. Gone of the days of installing third party websockets apache modules like [Rachet](http://socketo.me/).

I get this error after following the instructions in the above question.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
>
> WebSocket connection to 'ws://socket.localhost/' failed:

I'm using apache webserver, not litespeed, lighttpd, nginx or IIS.

By the way I'm using [Uniform Server](https://uniformserver.com).

### My first attempt (in case someone comments for me to show my work)

**Make sure that the following apache modules are turned on**

- mod_proxy_wstunnel
- mod_proxy_modules

**Edit the already existing file called httpd.conf to then insert this into it. Make sure you edit the correct file if you have duplicate file names for different apache versions**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName socket.localhost

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass "/ws2/"  "ws://localhost:8546/"
    ProxyPass "/wss2/"  "wss://localhost:8546/"
</VirtualHost>
```

**Test the websocket using this HTML page with inline javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = new WebSocket('ws://socket.localhost');
    socket.send('Test');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example that I use for GraphQL subscription via websocket.

IP & Port are meant to be replaced by your configuration.

Make sure you have these modules installed:

```sh
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
```

Site Config:

```sh
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName something.com
        ServerAdmin web@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/subscription            [NC]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
        RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://ip:port/$1 [P,L]
        ProxyPass "/subscriptions" "ws://ip:port/subscriptions"
        ProxyPassReverse "/subscriptions" "ws://ip:port/subscriptions"
        ProxyPass "/" "http://ip:port/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://ip:port/"
</VirtualHost>
```

```
/Subscription
```

Is my websocket endpoint. Yours might differ.